# Should we give money to street beggar?

Tags: practical-islam, sadaqah

Assalamu'alaikum,

In our area here are lots of street beggar. Whenever I go outside, I face at-least 15 beggars a day. I noticed that whenever they ask money to have food, then if I or anyone want to buy them food, they don't want to take food, rather want money.

What should we do?

Comment: Here's an extensive answer to a similar question: http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2500

Comment: @infatuated,, i just read the artical.. it is good. but it was also narrated that "It has been reported from Imam Baqir (a.s.) that he said: “Give the beggar something, even if he is riding on a horse.".. I didnt get it. If someone isn't poor then how he deserves it over others?

Comment: There are many other hadiths in which the Imams didn't respond uniformly to people begging. There are several considerations here other than the truthfulness of the beggar. You may ask a separate question on this problem and I may try to elaborate.

Comment: I personally never give to beggars because an overwhelming majority of them nowadays are scammers looking to make easy money and it is difficult to differentiate them on individual basis. I only give to charitable institutions with good reputation, which provide food and lodging to people who actually deserve it.

Comment: I also felt like it became a profession now-a-days. The more we give, the more beggars are raising. So often give money to mosque, or a beggar if he is old. But face problems when buying or eating foods in street, they keep standing beside us, and keep asking, if we give money to one, another and another one keep coming.. :|